# Associating with animals (a bit harsh?)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Find a message by associating each clue with an animal.  It may not be the first animal that you think of!  Once you have the message, identify all of the animals.

> Dream Electric
>
> Mythical Knees
>
> An edible stick
>
> A false lead to throw you off
>
> Desert
>
> Grreat
>
> Cheeky
>
> A hairless American is one kind of this
>
> Small, hairy land octopus
>
> You're nuts
>
> Lives in the front of the dictionary
>
> Fetches things for VIPs on a film set
>
> Fat with 'a posh box'

HINT:

Animals can be repeated and aren't necessarily real live animals, and at least one is misspelled

CHANGE:

Concerning the particularly difficult and probably a bit to 'trivia' first clue, I've changed 'Electric' to 'Dream Electric'

CHANGE #2:

To help things along, I've changed 'Stick' to 'An edible stick'

Comment: Very nice clue spectrum, from straightforward to esoteric to devious to downright dastardly

Comment: @humn  Thank you very much.  I expect that the more dastardly clues will be helped along by the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon what was already posted:

Dream Electric

> Sheep - From "Do Androids dream of electric sheep"

Mythical Knees

> Elephants (False internet factoid that elephants are the only mammal with 4 knees)

An edible stick

> Crab Stick

A false lead to throw you off

> Red Herring

Desert

> Eagle (From Desert Eagle)

Grreat

> Tiger (Tony the Tiger - Frosties Cereal)

Cheeky

> Monkey (From the term "Cheeky Monkey")

A hairless American is one kind of this

> Eagle (Bald Eagle)

Small, hairy land octopus

> Spider (Small, hairy with eight legs)

You're nuts

> Squirrel (nut collector)

Lives in the front of the dictionary

> Aardvark (First animal in the dictionary)

Fetches things for VIPs on a film set

> Gopher (Slur for film crew assistants)

Fat with 'a posh box'

> Elephant (Post box = Trunk, Elephants Trunk)

The Secret Message is:

> 'SecretMessage' (using the first letter of each answer)

Comment: You got it.  +1 Well done.

Answer (score 8):

Well, here are my guesses to get things rolling. I will embolden the ones I am confident in or received confirmation on.

Dream electric

> SHEEP, a reference to Philip K. Dick's *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*

Mythical Knees

> BEE, from the phrase *bee's knees*. (If this is correct, maybe a better clue would be *proverbial knees* or *idiomatic knees*.)

Stick

> BAT, a (rough) synonym for *stick*.

A false lead to throw you off

> **HERRING**, from *red herring* ([humn](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn))

Desert

> **EAGLE**, from *desert eagle* ([Deusovi](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)) (This answer is repeated below, which is why OP warned about repetition.)

Grreat

> **TIGER**, from Tony the Tiger, whose catch phrase is "They're grrrrreat!" (Perhaps this is why OP warned about the possibility of an unreal animal.)

Cheeky

> **MONKEY**, from the phrase *cheeky monkey* ([Peregrine Rook](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19765/peregrine-rook))

A hairless American is one kind of this

> **EAGLE**, from bald eagle.

Small, hairy land octopus

> SPIDER, perhaps. I originally had TARANTULA, and OP told me I had one half right (maybe he was referring to this).

You're nuts

> Perhaps BAT, from the expression *batty*, meaning crazy.

Lives in the front of the dictionary

> **AARDVARK**

Fetches things for VIPs on a film set

> GOPHER, a term sometimes used to describe runners on sets and elsewhere. It is sometimes spelled [GOFER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gofer) when referring to this position, which may be the misspelling warned about in the question.

Fat with 'a posh box'

> ELEPHANT, a large animal with a *trunk* (a posh word for *box*).

Comment: Mythical knees could be **UNICORN** and Desert relates to **CAMELS** I think

Comment: @Techidiot How so?  Just curious...

Comment: [False lead?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/herring) [Stick?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walking_stick) [Fetches things?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gofer)

Comment: @humn, I think you're definitely right about HERRING. I was countenancing that for *stick*, but it seems too straightforward...

Comment: @humn one of the two +1

Comment: @BrentHackers - Horse neighs(knees) and hence Mythical Horses can be Unicorn. Long shot :)

Comment: How about the added third, @Brent Hackers? It could also be a cheeky misspelled repeat.

Comment: @Techidiot  Ah! Ok.  ...@Silenus Bang on +1

Comment: @humn very clever.  Not giving any more away though :)

Comment: @humm You have to be right about "fetches things"

Comment: Fat with 'a posh box' could be referring to a cat, as in "fat cat" and "litter box", where litter refers to the carried vehicle that royal once used.

Comment: @Cody, that seems like an equally viable if not more viable interpretation. Especially since *trunk* isn't, in my opinion, a very bourgeois word.

Comment: @Silenus bourgeois? *quick-lookup* Oh!  Well I guess middle-class words just seem posh to me!

Comment: @BrentHackers, thanks for keeping us from going down too upper class a track :)

Comment: If I remember right, there was a Desert Kangaroo Rat..

Comment: You may need to look at some alternatives.  You have about 6 and a half correct so far.

Comment: Desert is "eagle" - the Desert Eagle is a type of gun.

Comment: Has “cheeky” been confirmed?  I have a **power**ful hunch that it’s [this](https://memegenerator.net/instance/41044095).

Comment: well done Deusovi and Peregrine +1s all round.

Comment: Not quite Silenus. 9 and a half!